# C# webClient download does throw error

Tags: c#, winforms, webclient

I'm trying to download a file through my application but I get an `UnauthorizedAccessException` yet the link is valid. What is wrong?

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.DownloadFile("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1dyuz10HTPIpJtXtIc7mDc2eHLJspo3lp", @"c:\ikon.png");
}
```

> 'NTI-X.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: NTI-X.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\mscorlib.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_sv_b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
>   Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.dll
>   'NTI-X.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: NTI-X.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_sv_b77a5c561934e089\System.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll
>   'NTI-X.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: NTI-X.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Transactions.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_sv_b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
>   System.Transactions Critical: 0 : http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/UnhandledOhanterat undantagNTI-X.exeSystem.Net.WebException, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089Ett undantag uppstod under en WebClient-begäran.   vid System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
>      vid System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(String address, String fileName)
>      vid NTI_X.Main..ctor() i C:\Users\elev\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\NTI-X\NTI-X\Main.cs:rad 108
>      vid NTI_X.Program.Main() i C:\Users\elev\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\NTI-X\NTI-X\Program.cs:rad 19System.Net.WebException: Ett undantag uppstod under en WebClient-begäran. ---&gt; System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Åtkomst till sökvägen c:\ikon.png nekas.
>      vid System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>      vid System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>      vid System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
>      vid System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
>      --- Slut på stackspårning för interna undantag ---
>      vid System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
>      vid System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(String address, String fileName)
>      vid NTI_X.Main..ctor() i C:\Users\elev\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\NTI-X\NTI-X\Main.cs:rad 108
>      vid NTI_X.Program.Main() i C:\Users\elev\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\NTI-X\NTI-X\Program.cs:rad 19System.UnauthorizedAccessException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089Åtkomst till sökvägen c:\ikon.png nekas.   vid System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>      vid System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>      vid System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
>      vid System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Åtkomst till sökvägen c:\ikon.png nekas.
>      vid System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>      vid System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>      vid System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
>      vid System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
>   An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
>   Ett undantag uppstod under en WebClient-begäran.

Comment: Well the link is valid, you can try it for yourself. About write acess, is it something i can do it from my application?

Comment: to write to the file-system root *could* require admin privileges on the user account and an elevated session; using a more appropriate file location would be simpler...

Comment: Please only tag [tag:visual-studio] if the question is ABOUT Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can see a `WebException` that is surfacing as an `UnauthorizedAccessException`; sounds like either a 401 on the url (`"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1dyuz10HTPIpJtXtIc7mDc2eHLJspo3lp"`), or that you don't have write access to the local download path (`@"c:\ikon.png"`) - my money would be on the second one: most operating systems don't like you writing to the file system root.

To try to identify which:

- see whether `curl` or similar, or an anonymous browser session, can download the url
- try using a different file location

Testing the link locally: yes, the url seems fine - reinforcing that that chosen file location is the most likely problem.

Comment: You were right, the location needed to change. Thanks for the help, i will approve this as the answer when i allowed to :)